# Error al descargar un .Zip con Axios

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, axios, zip

Tengo una API en django con la que descargo un archivo .zip del servidor:

```
class File_manager():
  def list_files(self, request, plantilla=''):
      ....

  def download(self, request, plantilla=''):
      # file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
      file_path = 'static/documents/pdf_zip/acta_final_plantilla.zip'
      if os.path.exists(file_path):
          with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
              response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/zip")
              response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
              return response
      else:
        return HttpResponse('error archivo no encontrado')
```

La api funciona  bien por si sola, pero ahora estoy haciendo una interfaz para consumirla con vue.js + Axios, y, aunque descarga el archivo, no lo puedo abrir.
*Código del frontend:*

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return{
            ...
        };
    },
    delimiters: ["${", "}$"],
    methods: {
        get_pdf_list() {
           ...
        },
        getZip() {

            let config = {
                headers: {
                    /*'Authorization' : 'Token 49b4ca783a4b68d4b2e163cd5436ce7926d20ad5',*/
                    'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
                    'responseType': 'blob'
                },
              } 
            /* Module Axios to make  HTTP request */
            axios.get(this.url_server +this.pdf_zip_api, config)
            .then(response => {
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]))
                const link = document.createElement('a')
                link.href= url
                link.setAttribute('download','acta_final.zip')
                document.body.appendChild(link)
                link.click();
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error))
        }

    }
})

app.mount('#app');
```

El error que me sale al intentar abrir el archivo es:
[image: cant open file ./file as archive]

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuánto pesa el archivo? ¿Qué aparece si lo abres con un editor de texto?

Comment: El archivo, por ahora pesa 1.093 KB, cuando lo abro en un editor de texto, aparece esto:   PK    `�R���59  uJ  -   acta_final_plantilla/Alejandro Diaz Ortiz.pdf��ֺ��&8?W�S��AzQ;DE@{�V... y mas

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50220546/2412893) en inglés, probablemente solo falta especificar el tipo de respuesta que esperas, agregando `responseType: 'arraybuffer',` en el objeto de configuración.

Comment: Funciono! muchas gracias.